# Windows Forms: Set form Visibility Based on Focus enabled of external window

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I would like to create a Windows Forms application that when run is only visible once another external window (notepad.exe) is enabled/focused. Any hints, I don't know where to begin.

If my form is running I would like it to popup when Notepad is enabled and disappear when  Notepad loses focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simply with API calls and a timer.  Add this line to your form's using statements:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Next, add these declarations to your form:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, 
    string lpWindowName); 

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

Finally, put a Timer on your form, and set its Enabled property to `true`.  In its Tick event, put this code:

```
IntPtr hWndNotepad = FindWindow(null, "Whatever.txt - Notepad");
IntPtr hWndForegroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
if (this.Handle != hWndForegroundWindow)
{
    this.Visible = (hWndNotepad == hWndForegroundWindow);
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should work.  The code is looking for a specific file to be open in Notepad; a different file would result in different text in the titlebar, so this code wouldn't work.  I think that if you change the FindWindow call to `FindWindow("notepad", null)` it would work with any open instance of Notepad (it might be "notepad.exe" - not sure).

**Update**: if you want your form to be visible if *any* instance of Notepad is open, you can instead put this code into your Timer's Tick event:

```
IntPtr hWndForegroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
bool NotepadIsForeground = false;
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
foreach (Process proc in procs)
{
    if (proc.MainWindowHandle == hWndForegroundWindow)
    {
        NotepadIsForeground = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (this.Handle != hWndForegroundWindow)
{
    this.Visible = NotepadIsForeground;
}
```

And you'll need this in your using directives:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Also not tested, but I'm doing so well today, so why bother?

Comment: That worked! It's the direction I want to go in. Thanks

One more question? If I click on my form it flashes continually instead of remaining focused (alternates between it and notepad). How do I fix it.

Comment: @zion: oops, told you I didn't test it. What was happening was that as soon as you clicked your form, *it* became the foreground window, so the next time the timer went off, your form made itself invisible again. I fixed the code sample.

Comment: @zion: OK, I just realized that from the way you phrased your question, you only want your form visible when Notepad is the focused window, so when you click on *your* form you would expect your form to then become invisible, since Notepad no longer has the focus. I think the simplest fix is to disable the timer in your form's Activated event, and then re-enable the timer in the form's Deactivate event. This sound right to you?

Comment: yeah that logic sounds correct, I appreciate the response and the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the Windows automation APIs for C#.  With these you should be able to look through all open windows and find Notepad.  I haven't looked at the API's a bunch but best base scenario is that there would be a activate/lostfocus event for the window you could handle.  Worst case, you could just poll every 100 ms or so and look to see if the Notepad window has focus.